# Limit of a natural log

Tags: limits

I have this limit

> $\lim_{x\to0^+}\big(\dfrac1x\big)^{\ln(x)}$

Can somebody help me understand how this limit equals $0$?

Answer (score 2):

In these cases it's useful to look at the logarithm of your function, that is
$$
\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!\ln x}=(\ln x)\ln\frac{1}{x}=-(\ln x)^2
$$
Therefore you have to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{-(\ln x)^2}
$$
Can you go on?

---

A word on explanation: if you denote by $y$ your given expression and $z=\ln y$, then $y=e^z$. In this case it turns out that $z$ can be easily simplified and $y$ rewritten in a simpler way for computing the limit.

In many other cases, when you have a limit in the form
$$
\lim f(x)^{g(x)}
$$
the limit of $z=\ln(f(x)^{g(x)}=g(x)\ln f(x)$ can be computed more easily than the limit of $y=f(x)^{g(x)}$ and then we can use the continuity of the exponential. Namely, if $\lim z=a$, then
$$
\lim y = \lim e^z = e^a
$$
with almost obvious extensions when $a=\infty$ or $a=-\infty$.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont understand the first part of what you wrote.

Comment: Where did you get ln 1/xlnx?

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa $(\dfrac 1x)^{\ln(x)} = \dfrac{1}{x^{\ln(x)}}$

Comment: What about the ln in front of that ?

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa I showed more steps.

Comment: I can't understand where the e comes from

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa If $y=\ln z$, then $z=e^y$.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not understanding , from the very first step including the ln at the front.

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions , so you can rewrite your limit as $e^{\ln((\frac{1}x)^{\ln(x)})}$

Comment: Please also explain the ln upfront of 1/xlnx. Thankyou... because one of you states that it is without ln and the other writes it with

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa it is the same thing as what egreg as said , and what ive explained in the comment. user egreg just omited the $e$ as it is understood that is what happens and has included the next step for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

$$\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln (x)}=\\\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}x^{-(1)\ln (x)}=\\\underset{x\to
   0^+}{\text{lim}}x^{-\ln (x)}=$$
Using property:

$$a^b=e^{b \ln (a)}$$

and then:

$$\\\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}e^{-\ln (x) \ln (x)}=\\\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}e^{-\ln ^2(x)}=0$$

Comment: Can you please edit this with the required format? So i can understand better.

Comment: What you wrote at the end , the last two equations, isn't exp raised to the (−ln(x)ln(x))??

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!